# Data import and processing - CSV

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a number of data sources stored as CSVs and a database table structure in 3NF on SQL Server 2008r2. Some of the columns within the data sources are unrequired.

What I would like to do is to insert the data from each data source into a separate temporary table where data types (and ideally column names) are declared based on the data being inserted. If this is not possible importing the data as the char datatype would help.

From here I would like to select the relevant data into my standard database structure and once complete drop the temporary tables.

I think I will have to use some cast statements to ensure the data is in the right format. I am happy to write a stored procedure to do this although the data is published periodically and occasionally the structure is changed so it will require some manual work.

I have tried to do this with a BULK INSERT but I receive Msg 208 regarding an invalid object name for the temporary table.

```
USE db1;
GO
BULK INSERT #TempDetails FROM 'C:\Documents\Data\Text Files\Details.txt'
WITH
    (
        DATAFILETYPE = 'char'
        , FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
        , ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    );
```

Returns

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 82, Line 2
Invalid object name '#TempDetails'.
```

What is the best way for me to achieve this?

My fall back alternative is to import the CSVs into Access and then import that into SQL for the processing but I would like this in code so it is easy to replicate.

Comment: Bulk Insert should be the easiest way of doing what you want. Can you provide a sample of your code (particularly how your temp table is declared and how you are attempting to retrieve the data)?

Comment: `BULK INSERT` requires the target object to exist already. Using `OPENROWSET` will allow the `SELECT...INTO...FROM...` construct, thus bypassing this requirement